# Java: Can't access variable?

Tags: java, variables

So i'm having a bit of a problem trying to compare two strings declared in the Main class. I've messed around with it and i really can't get it to work! The problem is in the if() statement where i compare the variables...

```
public class Main {

    public String oldContent = "";
    public String newContent = "";

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        Main downloadPage = new Main();
        downloadPage.downloadPage();
        oldContent = newContent;

        for (;;) {
            downloadPage.downloadPage();
            if (!oldContent.equals(newContent)) { // Problem
                System.out.println("updated!");
                break;
            }
            Thread.currentThread().sleep(3000);
        }
    }

    private void downloadPage() {
        // Code to download a page and put the content in newContent.
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the variables are instance members, whereas the for happens in a static method.
try moving the actual function to an instance method (not static), or conversely make the data members static as well.

Comment: I tried ticking it at first, but stackoverflow was being b*tchy! Ticked now! :)

Answer (score 2):

You may use name of the object you have created (downloadPage ) to access to the parameters:
in the main finction use following instead of parameter names only:

```
downloadPage.oldContent
downloadPage.newContent
```

Answer (score 1):

The variables are inside the `Main` object:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    Main downloadPage = new Main();
    downloadPage.downloadPage();  // Access them like you accessed the method
    downloadPage.oldContent = downloadPage.newContent;

    for (;;) {
        downloadPage.downloadPage();
        if (!downloadPage.oldContent.equals(downloadPage.newContent)) {
            System.out.println("updated!");
            break;
        }
        Thread.currentThread().sleep(3000);
    }
}
```

Do consider using getters and setters instead of exposing the fields.

Answer (score 0):

See [non static/ static variable error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5590949/non-static-static-variable-problem)